# Accessing properties of attached file

Tags: views, theming, files

I have a custom content type which allows one file to be attached to it. In the teaser of the node I want to fine-print the date of the file's (rather than node's) last modification and its size. How can I access those properties in a suggestion template file or in the field-based View that generates the list of teasers?

I am using Drupal 7, and version 7.x-3 of the Views module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, but in the views settings page, you add a relationship to the field that holds the file.  Then, when you add a field, you should see an option for **File: Size** in the list.  Other fields for file into appear, but mtime isn't one of them.

A hackish way to get mtime is to use [stat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) in your view template, but I would do that as a last resort if you can't find a module to add this as a view field.

Comment: Thanks, partial answer but a very mind-opening one. Thank you! I will try to submit a feat request for views so that they add modification date through a relationship.

Comment: The problem is that mtime, along with a lot of other file information, isn't stored in the database.  A module would have to scan the files, store it in a table, and then expose the data to views.

Comment: Now that I have attempted to write code, I understand why you called stat a last resort. I could not find a way to convert remote link (http) into a local path (file system path) which is needed as a stat parameter.

Comment: You need to get DOCUMENT_ROOT.  Read the comments on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/base_path/6.  But I think you can also do all of it through D7 File API.